# problems with scrollview, not scrolling full length

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view, added in the IB, and also I added a lot of objects/controls to it on IB itself. Some of them are added to the scrollview but they are out of its bounds.

Back in the class, I'm setting its content size like this

```
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height + 500);
```

The scrolling length I observe is not that much. I just observe like 500 px (while the height I set in the content size is around 900 px).

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what is the value of self.view.bounds.size.height? NSLog(@"%f",self.view.bounds.size.height);

Comment: for sure you use some sort of dynamic alignment (i.e. constraints) and to that given moment the view has now discreet height. you will have to add more code so that we can help you.

Comment: @DharaParekh: 480 px.

Comment: There is no other code related to this scrollview. Nothing is added programatically. However, all the constraints are relative to the top of scrollview.

Comment: try self.view.frame.size.height instead of self.view.bounds.size.height

Answer (score 0):

I use the IB to set the scroll view and the inner controls and I let the scroll view to be longer than the view area it self as  why do you need to set it inside the code unless you draw the inner controls dynamically at the runtime ...I hope it is useful

Comment: If you have a question please use the "ask question" link